# $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ be an entire function having Taylor's series expansion

Tags: complex-analysis

I came across the following problem:

> Let $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ be an entire function having Taylor's series expansion as $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$$. If $f(x)=u(x,0)$ and $f(iy)=iv(0,y)$, then how can I show that $a_{2n}=0 \forall n.$

I do not know what to do next. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: That's not true; $f(z) =z$ is a counterexample. In general, every odd function $f$ with real Taylor coefficients satisfies $f(x) = u(x,0)$ and $f(iy) = iv(0,y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is (a). Function $f$ satisfies the required conditions if and only if $f$ is odd (that is, $a_{2n} = 0$ for every $n$) and all Taylor coefficients $a_k$ are real.

Comment: How it can be shown?